# count number of rows of a specific value IReport

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have a column `Status` and I'd like to count how many lines are "`Pendings`" and how many are "`Finalized`"

I tried this:

```
Variable class = java.lang.Integer
Calculation = Sum
ResetType = Report
Increment type = None
Variable expression = $F{tbl_suspensao_status}.equals("Finalized")  ? 0 : 1
```

But it did not work.

Query:

```
SELECT
     tbl_suspensao.`codigoBeneficiario` AS tbl_suspensao_codigoBeneficiario,
     tbl_suspensao.`contrato` AS tbl_suspensao_contrato,
     tbl_suspensao.`data_fim` AS tbl_suspensao_data_fim,
     tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` AS tbl_suspensao_data_inicio,
     tbl_suspensao.`status` AS tbl_suspensao_status,
     tbl_usuario.`nome` AS tbl_usuario_nome,
     tbl_suspensao.`nomeBeneficiario` AS tbl_suspensao_nomeBeneficiario
FROM
     `tbl_usuario` tbl_usuario INNER JOIN `tbl_suspensao` tbl_suspensao ON tbl_usuario.`codigo` = tbl_suspensao.`usuario_id`
WHERE
 AND tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` BETWEEN  $P{Data_Inicio} AND $P{Data_Fim}
```

Comment: What means "it did not work"? Which values displayed for this variables?
Show report data and report result for this counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
   sum(if(Status = "Pendings", 1, 0)) Pendings, 
   sum(if(Status = "Finalized", 1, 0)) Finalized
 from table
```

Or so

```
select 
    sum(Status = "Pendings") Pendings, 
    sum(Status = "Finalized") Finalized 
  from t1
```

[**Demo on sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17a25/2)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT status, count(*) from table where status='pending' or status='finalized' 
group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong order 1 and 0. Change expression to

```
Variable expression = $F{tbl_suspensao_status}.equals("Finalized")  ? 1 : 0
```

P.S. Calculation sum in SQL is SQL-solution but not iReport-solution